# New Wyeast private stcok yeast strains?

Tags: yeast, ale, beer

Has anyone had any experiences with the new Wyeast Private Reserve yeast strains.  I just bought a Cask Ale, and wondered if anyone had tried a beer with it yet?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Would you please fix the typo in your question and also be a little more specific with what you're asking? The site is intended to be more of a Q&A site rather than a discussion forum.

Comment: @Joe I agree, I voted to close as NARQ